# Why doesn't crystal's type inference work on classes as expected?

Tags: crystal-lang

Why can I define a method like that in Crystal:

```
def foo(bar): String
  bar.to_json
end

foo({"x" => 1, "y" => 2})
```

but that kind of type inference doesn't work with classes:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(bar)
    @bar = bar
  end

  def foo: String
    @bar.to_json
  end
end


Foo.new({"x" => 1, "y" => 2}).foo
```

and it ends up with

`Error: can't infer the type of instance variable '@bar' of Foo`

What am I missing about Crystal's type inference and what is the workaround for this?

Comment: You probably need to initialize a Foo somewhere (`Foo.new(xxx)`) so it can get a clue as to what @bar will end up as...maybe it's not as smart with class variables as it is with methods (which it just ignores if nobody calls them)?

Comment: @rogerdpack nope, that doesn't work too.

Comment: Hmm might be expected: https://crystal-lang.org/reference/syntax_and_semantics/type_inference.html

Comment: @rogerdpack if so, I would be very grateful to know what is a work-around for this case, in other words, how to I accept any type that has method `to_json: String` in constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent class based approach is making the class a generic:

```
require "json"

class Foo(T)
  def initialize(@bar : T)
  end

  def foo
    @bar.to_json
  end
end


puts Foo.new({"x" => 1, "y" => 2}).foo
```

Instance variables need their type set in one way or another because lexicographical type flow analysis is much harder and thus slower to do for them. Also classes build the base of your program so typing them as narrow as possible not only makes the compiler's job easier, it also makes them easier to use. Too open type restrictions on instance variables can lead to quite long and confusing error messages.

You can read more at the original proposal introducing the change to require type annotations on instance variables: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/2390